# Fastest way to split Word document to separate files

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm looking for most efficient way to split one huge file to small files. Every small file is one paragraph from big one.
It's not a problem if big file has ~100 paragraphs, but if its over 12k its took to long time.

Now I'm seting bookmark for each paragraph and next I'm inserting each bookmark in new file (I'm seting bookmark beacause sometimes I have to insert more than one paragraph, but now I don't want complicate exapmple, so I'm describe my problem using paragraphs).

This is my code (ofc its a simple example without extra logic and error handling).
Creation new file, save and close takes the most time.

```
Private Sub InsertBookmarks()
    Dim p As Paragraph
    Dim counter As Long
    For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        counter = counter + 1
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "File" & Format(counter, "00000#"), p.Range
    Next p
    ActiveDocument.Save
    Set p = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub SplitToSeparateFiles()

    Dim path As String
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim b As Bookmark

    path = ActiveDocument.path & "\"

    WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros
    For Each b In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        Set doc = Documents.Add(Visible:=False)
        doc.Range.FormattedText = b.Range
        doc.SaveAs2 FileName:=path & b.Name
        doc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
    Next b

    Set b = Nothing
    Set doc = Nothing

End Sub
```

I considered the change my code to handle splitting using WordOpenXml behind the scenes but I didn't find any solution.
I may use VSTO add-in if someone has any idea in .net environment.

Any idea for more efficient way?

Comment: What gives the desire to make the process "more efficient"? What do you mean by "efficient"?

Comment: Now it's took long time, sometimes >8h.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an excerpt from a C# program I use that uses the FreeSpire.Doc nuget package to read a Word Document. I know your questions was VBA but you mentioned .NET at the end, so I figure you're not averse to creating something in C# or VB (vsual studio should be free for small time use)

```
        using (Document document = new Document())
        {
            document.LoadFromFileInReadMode(@"C:\temp\word.docx", FileFormat.Docx);

            foreach (Section s in document.Sections)
            {
                int pCount = 0;
                foreach (Paragraph p in s.Paragraphs)
                {
                    File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\p"+pCount+".txt", p.Text);
                    pCount++;
                }
            }
        }
```

I don't expect it will take several hours to write 12,000 files, but I don't have a word document with 12,000 paragraphs to test it with; let me know your results?

Edit:

The following program created 12000 files in 41 seconds on an SSD equipped Core i7:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 12000; i++){
                File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\x\" + i + ".txt", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Using it as a benchmark and assuming that it could take up to a minute to load a massive document, I would be hopeful that a .NET app doing the splitting would take a few minutes on a word doc with tens of thousands of paragraphs

Edit2:

Creating word files. The real process **might** be like this, if you're reading every paragraph out of a source and making a new doc with that same paragraph (try assigning the old paragraph to the new document):

```
        using (Document document = new Document())
        {
            document.LoadFromFileInReadMode(@"C:\temp\word.docx", FileFormat.Docx);

            foreach (Section s in document.Sections)
            {
                int pCount = 0;
                foreach (Paragraph p in s.Paragraphs)
                {
                    Document document = new Document();
                    Section s = document.AddSection();
                    s.Paragraphs.Add(p);
                    document.SaveToFile(@"c:\temp\x\" + pCount + ".docx", FileFormat.Docx);
                }
            }
        }
```

I created 1200 word documents in 15 seconds:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1200; i++){
            Document document = new Document();
            Section s = document.AddSection();
            Paragraph p = s.AddParagraph();
            TextRange textRange1 = p.AppendText(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            textRange1.CharacterFormat.TextColor = Color.Blue;
            textRange1.CharacterFormat.FontSize = 15;
            textRange1.CharacterFormat.Bold = true;

            TextRange textRange2 = p.AppendText(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            textRange2.CharacterFormat.TextColor = Color.Black;
            textRange2.CharacterFormat.FontSize = 10;

            TextRange textRange3 = p.AppendText(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            textRange3.CharacterFormat.TextColor = Color.Red;
            textRange3.CharacterFormat.FontSize = 8;
            textRange3.CharacterFormat.Italic = true;

            document.SaveToFile(@"c:\temp\x\" + i + ".docx", FileFormat.Docx);

            Console.Out.Write("\r" + i);
        }
    }
```

I did note that there was a huge amount of garbage collection going on. Reducing that would perhaps speed things up a bit, if you can work out how

Comment: I see that your code create txt file. I have to have new documents with formatting like in source file. But I'll check it (maybe there will be other options). My big file is some kind of dictionary (every entry shuold be in separate file) with bold, italic, numbering list (paragraphs are only for simplicity example) But thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll check it. Thanks a lot for wasting your time for me.